# C - Do "_Thread_local" global variables always exist on separate page?

Tags: c, malloc, pthreads, mmap, thread-local

Will "_Thread_local" storage class global variables always be placed at separate page? Or, just like those allocated with user library "malloc()", can those be placed at available spaces within already allocated pages?

In other words, is "_Thread_local" global variable allocated with malloc(), or mmap() at the time of thread creation, and will accessing it frequently result in data cache and dTLB miss?

Comment: The standard doesn't mandate it, but it is likely that an implementation would use a new page.

Comment: ... which is a separate matter from how or when it is allocated, and from any deleterious effects related to hardware memory caches.  These latter considerations are likely to vary from implementation to implementation.

Comment: I'd be tempted to expect that "thread local storage" is actually a single thread local pointer that points to boring old memory taken from the heap (e.g. using `malloc()`) and that there's no guarantee that (e.g.) 1 byte of thread local data per thread will waste an entire page for padding. I tested this on Windows - printing the address of the same thread local variable in different threads in some C code, and found that the addresses are only 320 bytes apart.

Comment: @Brendan Thanks! Actually I haven't thought that method. I will test on Linux myself with both gcc and clang, coupled with glibc.

Comment: @Brendan Even though I'm gonna test it myself again, but I wonder "_Thread_local __attribute__((aligned(4096)))" will be effective to separate the cold variable to consume hot memory space for _Thread_locals.